# GET request getting undefined in urls

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, frontend

I'm trying to get data from an API get call and then edit that data using patch call but it seems like my get request is not working in here. I'm new in react, any help would be appriciated. 
I'm quite new to this. But I cannot find much help online for that matter. 
This is my editInvice.js

```
import {
    Button, Card,
    CardBody,
    CardHeader, Col, Form,
    FormGroup, Input,
    Label, Row,
} from 'reactstrap';
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';
import {editInvoice, getInvoiceDetails} from "../../../helpers/api";


export default () => {

    //
    // var len = window.location.href.length;
    // var id = window.location.href[len-1];


    //TODO THIS IS NOT THE REACT METHOD TO FETCH ID FROM THE URLTT

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        'id': '',
        'invoice_number': '',
        'invoice_date': '',
        'invoice_due_date': '',
        'invoice_place_of_supply': '',
        'invoice_destination': '',
        'invoice_destination_address': '',
        'invoice_destination_pincode': '',
        'invoice_gst': '',

        'invoice_quiz_id':'',


        'invoice_salesperson': '',
        'invoice_lr_number': '',
        'invoice_vehicle_placement_date': '',
        'invoice_vehicle_number': '',
        'invoice_service_month': '',
        'invoice_item_details': '',

        'invoice_rate': '',
        'invoice_tax': '',
        'invoice_amount': '',
        'invoice_quiz': '',
        'invoice_owner': '',
        'invoice_quantity': '',


        'lr_number': '',
        'billing_party_name': '',
        'origin_address': '',
        'origin_pincode': '',
        'vehicle_placement_date': '',
        'vehicle_number': '',
        'item_details': '',
        'item_quantity': '',
        'total_amount': '',
        'tax': '',

    });


    useEffect(() => {
        const getNetwork = async () => {
            const invoice_details = await getInvoiceDetails(form.invoice_quiz);
            setForm(invoice_details);
        };
        getNetwork();
    }, [setForm]);


    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        setForm({
            ...form,
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            alert(JSON.stringify(form));
            await editInvoice(form, form.invoice_quiz_id);
            alert('done')
        } catch (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e))
        }
    };

    return (
        <Card>
            <CardHeader>
                <strong>Edit Invoice</strong>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
                <Form method={'post'} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Row form>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="origin">Invoice number</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" valid={form.invoice_number}
                                       onChange={handleInputChange}/>

                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>

                        <Col md={4}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="origin">Invoice ID</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="id" id="id" value={form.id}
                                       onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>

                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="scheduled_date">Invoice Date</Label>
                                <Input type="datetime-local" name="invoice_date" id="invoice_date"
                                       value={form.invoice_date}
                                       onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Button color={"primary"} size={"lg"}>Create</Button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <Button color={"link"} size={"lg"}>Cancel</Button>
                </Form>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
```

This is my get API call:

```
const GET_INVOICE = '/suppliers/invoiceapi/';
export const getInvoiceDetails = (id) => loadSecureUrl(`${GET_INVOICE}${id}`);
```

This is my patch API call

````
const EDIT_INVOICE = 'suppliers/invoiceapi';
export const editInvoice = (data,id) => loadSecureUrl(`${EDIT_INVOICE}${id}`, {
    data: data,
    method: 'patch'
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing method in your `GET` functionality. I hope this will answer your query.

```
const GET_INVOICE = '/suppliers/invoiceapi/';
    export const getInvoiceDetails = (id) => loadSecureUrl(`${GET_INVOICE}${id}`, {
    method: 'get'
});
```

Comment: I'm getting ```Not Found: /suppliers/invoiceapi/``` this in backend whereas I want ``` /suppliers/invoiceapi/80```
where 80 is the ID

Comment: @chirag have you console the `id` and `url` before the call? Are they correct before the call made?